# Limits of a progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, triangle-inequality

Question:

"Show that a progression $(a_n)_{n\ge1}$ applies for the following implication
$$a_n \rightarrow a ~\text{when}~ n \rightarrow \infty, \Rightarrow |a_n| \rightarrow |a| ~\text{when}~ n \rightarrow \infty $$
Does the implication hold the other way?"

So I'm a bit stuck, first I don't really know how to show if the implication applies? Secondly, I've tried using the reverse triangle inequality when investigating if the implication holds the other way, which gives me

$$||a_n|-|a|| \le |a_n-a| $$
but then I'm also stuck as above. I assume that the implication doesn't hold, but I cannot seem to show it mathematically. Any advice?

Thanks, Sincerely.

Comment: Then take $n\to \infty $ to conclude... for your second question, the converse doesn't hold. Example, $a_n=(-1)^n$.

Comment: Hmm, så to conclude the first question  $$|a_n-a|<\epsilon \\
||a_n|-|a||<\epsilon $$ ? Thanks.